# Socket IO C++ and rooming

Tags: c++, websocket, socket.io, ipc

First, I am novice to socket.io.

I have an algorithm written in C++ which needs to act as a socket.io client (at least this is how I see it....) and communicate with a server which creates two rooms:

1 . "Telemetry" from which I need to receive 3 `double` values formatted as json:

```
{
  "alt": 234.344,
  "yaw": 24.3,
  "vel": 14.3
}
```

2 . "CurrentLocation" to which I need to send 3 `double` values formatted as json:

```
{
   "location": {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          34.87643,
          45.32452,
          123.54
          ],
          "type": "Point"
         } 
   } 
}
```

I am trying to use [socket.io C++ client](https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/) because all my code is in C++.

I successfully established the connection with the server:

```
sio::client conclient;
conclient.conncet("http://192.168.0.1:8707");//->[connect] Successful connection
```

But I am not sure what am I suppose to do now?
According to the documentation I haven't seen support in rooming in the socket.io C++ client, is that correct? if not, How do I send the message to "Telemetry" room? how do I receive from "CurrentLocation"

Comment: I suppose you have data somewhere in your client program, data that you should send to the server in the form of JSON? Then you first need to create the JSON from the data you have. Then you should just send it as text. If the server expects some other kind of protocol you need to read the documentation for the server.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - My algorithm creates the data which I need to send. but how exactly do I "just send it as text" and to the correct room?

Comment: All JSON libraries I know of have functions to "dump" a JSON object as text. This is how you create the text to be sent. Then you use the normal "send" functions to send the text to the socket. What you mean by "room" and how to specifically send to such a "room" is unknown since you haven't told us anything about the protocol being used. Please read the documentation of the service you use!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude by normal "send" function do you mean `emit`? as far as I see this I am using http protocol and socket.io should support rooming. (at least the js version does)

Comment: @BennyK it is very unclear what you are aiming for. Please be sure to check the guidelines for asking questions. Also, good questions will show effort on the askers side.

Comment: @darune Well, looked to me that what I want to do is simple: send a message in json format from C++ application via socket.io

Comment: @BennyK you show no effort - eg. what have tried so far ? what errors did you get ? etc.

Comment: @darune The only thing I succeeded thus far is connection establishment as I wrote in my Q, after that I really not sure what I am suppose to do

Comment: @BennyK Then you probably want to try something first - or go into more detail about what you see as missing the API, tec.

Comment: @darune have already done that, or so I think. In the js version there is a concept of rooming, so I can send messages to specific rooms, but I didn't find (for my understanding) an equivalent in the CPP version, so first I wanted to know if I am right